# Type-less catch block in PHP

Tags: php, exception

Has PHP any ability to catch all types of exceptions in one catch block?
Is there any way to do this:

```
try  
{  
throw new Exception; OR throw new MyException;  
}  
catch(???)  
{
// Catch both exception types  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*Exception*](http://php.net/class.exception) is the super class of all exceptions. So:

```
catch (Exception $e) {
    // Catches any exception
}
```

Comment: While this is true, it's very often a horrible idea and if misused will lead to nasty bugs.

Comment: Technically true, there have been some known bugs with pecl packages & other built-in extensions which threw a non-Exception derived Exception (I think it was SoapFault a while back). Those should be reported as bugs and are usually fixed pretty quick.